# jquery click function always returns highest value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I insert elements to the DOM, after that I want to bind a click function to these elements.
This works, but for some reason the links that were created all return the same value, which
is the highest value 'px_amount' has after looping. Very strange :) The first console.log();
does return the right value, and I can see it increment after each iteration. I added a simple console.log() to the click function, for sake of simplicity.

```
for(var i=1; i<=bullet_amount; i++)
{               
    $('<a id="bullet-'+i+'">'+i+' </a>').appendTo('#bullet-nav');

    px_amount = (i-1)*ratio*3450;
    console.log(px_amount);
    $("#bullet-"+i).live('click', function() {
        console.log(px_amount);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a closure to capture the *value* of `i` reather than the *reference*:

```
for(var i=1; i<=bullet_amount; i++) {
    (function(iVal) {
        $('<a id="bullet-'+iVal+'">'+iVal+' </a>').appendTo('#bullet-nav');

        var px_amount = (iVal-1)*ratio*3450;
        console.log(px_amount);
        $("#bullet-"+iVal).live('click', function() {
            console.log(px_amount);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Ok, this solution worked, the ival argument was not needed, though.

Comment: for(var i=1; i<=bullet_amount; i++) {
     (function() {
         $('<a id="bullet-'+i+'">'+i+' </a>').appendTo('#bullet-nav');

         var px_amount = (i-1)*ratio*3450;
         console.log(px_amount);
         $("#bullet-"+i).live('click', function() {
             console.log(px_amount);
         });
     })();
 }

Answer (score 5):

This is a very frequent problem : the variable `i` is the same for all callbacks, that is the one of the enclosing scope.

A common solution is this :

```
for(var i=1; i<=bullet_amount; i++)
{               
    (function(i){
      $('<a id="bullet-'+i+'">'+i+' </a>').appendTo('#bullet-nav');
      px_amount = (i-1)*ratio*3450;
      console.log(px_amount);
      $("#bullet-"+i).live('click', function() {
         console.log(px_amount);
      });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Your function declaration needs to become a function expression. This will currently throw a syntax error (at the invoking parentheses).

Comment: @JamesAllardice +1 Yes. Typed too fast. Fixed it.